# Google route api for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

I am working on **WP7**, i have integrated google maps in map control.

I want to show a path on map, i have source and destination positions.

As **bing** is providing as [**soap service**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx#Y1833) for path between two points.

is there is any google soap service for path API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Directions API](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/directions/)